# C++ Cannot print vector of string element

Tags: c++, vector

Why I can't print third element of my vector ?
I'm need a words that will be divided to vector and after that, they will be printed.
But my third element of vector isn't showing in the terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void divideTextCommand(string txt, vector<string> cmd)
{

    string word = "";
    for (auto x : txt)
        {
            if (x == ' ')
            {
                cmd.push_back(word);
                word = "";
            }
            else
            {
                word = word + x;
            }
        }
        cmd.push_back(word);

}


int main()
{
    cout << "Command:" << endl;
    string textCommand; getline(cin, textCommand);
    vector<string> command;
    cout << " " << endl;
    divideTextCommand(textCommand, command);

    cout << command[2];

    return 0;
}
```

In my terminal program looks like this

```
bob@msi:~/Desktop/project$ ./output
Command:
barry jack fred john
 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Unrelated: writing code like this throws people (me) into a hissy fit: `string textCommand; getline(cin, textCommand);` - Why are those on a single line? Alienating readers of your code is not good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently not providing a reference to command:

```
void divideTextCommand(string txt, vector<string> cmd)
                                    // ^ this is a copy, original is not edited
```

I would suggest you simply return your command:

```
std::vector<std::string> divideTextCommand(std::string txt) {
    std::vector<std::string> cmd
    ...
    return cmd; // Thanks to RVO, this is no more expensive and is much clearer.
```

Comment: And if you're worried, "OMG! Copying the `vector`! Such a profligate expense!"  Know that you are not the first, and some really smart folks came up with [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) as a result.

Comment: @user4581301 Those are the best additions ever! Mandatory copy elision or (N)RVO.
Next step: Elide the copy/move of an argument to a function from being copied/moved if passed by as a return value - let it be the same entity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `cmd` by reference:

```
void divideTextCommand(string txt, vector<string> &cmd)
//                                                ^
```

As it is, `command` in `main` remains empty so accessing element [2] is UB.

But I prefer Fantastic Mr Fox's suggestion - split your words into a locally declared array in `divideTextCommand` and then return that as the function result.  It's more natural and carries no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in:

```
void divideTextCommand(string txt, vector<string> cmd)
```

the `vector<string> cmd` inside the function now will only be a copy of the inputed version, and will be stored in a completely different memory location. Therefore, any changes made to `cmd` inside the function will **not** reflect back to the original variable. This is called `pass by value`.

To solve it, you simply use `pass by reference`, by adding a `&` before your param:

```
void divideTextCommand(string txt, vector<string> &cmd)
```

By doing this we're **refering** to the address of `cmd`, and changes will be made to both versions.

Result (with your code, adding the `&`):

```
Command:
fred george alex john

alex
```

More info :

- [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)
- https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/reference